# Most cost effective way to host mutiple websites on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-app-service-plans

I'm new to azure and I have a trial account, but the credits are only available for 30 days. I think their previous offer with monthly credits was much better, it gives you more chance to get up and running efficiently and see what works best.

Anyway I have 4 websites, three of which require SQL Server dB. I'm trying to figure out if I can use Azure in a cheap and cost effective way.
All require custom domain and SSL, which means the B1 App Service plan is a minimum requirement, costing about £40-£50 per site. This is already completely unaffordable for me, for small, basic sites. I think it's ridiculous that a website with custom domain and SSL is so expensive on Azure. Maybe Azure is not for me.

I read about using Clouflare on the Shared App Service plan, but I'm not too keen on this solution. I've tried Clouflare in the past and had some issues with performance. Also the free version SSL only encrypts users to Cloudflare. So I'm looking for a solution without Clouflare.

I'm thinking to use an Azure VM but need some suggestions.

- Which VM would be a good option for 4 websites ranging from a couple hundred to a couple thousand visits per month?
- Can a B1S VM handle a website with dB?
- Do I have SQL Server installed on the VM or do I connect to a managed SQL database?
- Do I require a SSL certificate for each site or only one certificate for the VM?
- Do I require any paid service link CI or anything to deploy my asp.net core sites to the VM?
- Is it worth the effort managing the VM?

Any advice appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are charged with Azure App Service Plan, which is a platform for hosting your apps. You can deploy many web apps in one App Service Plan, for example: B1. But, be careful with the workloads. If your application is a big one, the B1 plan would be  exhausted to host 4.

Secondly, you can try to use VM. Since the visit amount is small, I think the B series VM can handle the requests. And if there is not many db operations, you can install SQl server in the VM.

Thirdly, if all your website are under one domain. For example: web1.domain.com , web2.domain.com, web3.domain.com,  web4.domain.com.  Then you need to apply for a wildcard certificate *.domain.com. Or you can apply for 4 separate certificate.

Another solution for certificate is to deploy your web apps under a domain: www.domain.com/web1....Then you just need one certificate.

Finally, you can change the VM size if the performance is not good.

Comment: If you’re a Microsoft partner, I recommend you visiting aka.ms/devchat for personalized support on Azure. It’s free and 24x5.